# send log through email using RUBY

Tags: ruby, email, loops, logging

I have a loop that goes through 100 times and `puts` something to the screen. EX:

```
1.upto(100) { |i| puts i }
#=>1
#=>2
#=>...100
```

Instead of using `puts` to display the result in my terminal, I need to store the result in a log file (or plain text) to send in an email to `test@test.com`.

EX:

```
1.upto(100) do |i| 
    x = []
    x << i
end

x.email.send(test@test.com)
```

Granted the above wouldn't work, that's the idea. I don't want to send 100 emails, but I want to send the result of each loop `#{i}` to `test@test.com` all inside one email. Is there a gem or easy way to manage this?

Comment: What does this have to do with logging?

Comment: I am trying to create a log file of the errors/successes. I created an extremely simplistic example to represent my point, but the end goal is analyze response codes and log an error/success message based on those response codes. I just need to know how to print to a log file, thus the example I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
File.open(yourfile, 'w') do |file|
    (1..100).each do |num|
       file.write(num) 
    end
end
```